# Apple script to listen for yes or no answer

Tags: automation, applescript, voice-recognition

I actually have this script working, (a surprise for me being a complete beginner) but I just wanted to make sure that this script doesn't have any excess code that I dont need. Or if there is a better way to do this please comment! I am eventually trying to create a series of voice commands.

```
tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
set l1 to {"yes", "sure", "yes please", "open mail"}
set l2 to {"no", "no thanks", "not now"}
set no_answer to {"no", "no thanks", "not now"}

set answer to listen for l1 & l2 with prompt "Would you like me to open your email"
l1 contains answer
l2 contains no_answer


end tell

if l1 contains answer then
say "yes answer"

else if l2 contains no_answer then
say "no answer"
end if

end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should only include commands within a tell block that belong to the application you are "telling". Build the lists outside the block.

```
set l1 to {"yes", "sure", "yes please", "open mail"}
set l2 to {"no", "no thanks", "not now"}
```

This does not do anything.

```
l1 contains answer
l2 contains no_answer
```

l2 will always contain no_answer because they are two static lists.

```
else if l2 contains no_answer
```

Try something like this instead:

```
set l1 to {"yes", "sure", "yes please", "open mail"}
set l2 to {"no", "no thanks", "not now"}

activate application "SpeechRecognitionServer"

try
    tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer" to set answer to listen for l1 & l2 with prompt "Would you like me to open your email" giving up after 20
on error number -128
    say "User did not respond"
    error number -128
end try

if l1 contains answer then
    say "yes answer"

else if l2 contains answer then
    say "no answer"
end if
```